# AWS EC2 react app deployment have warnings? How to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have ssh into the EC2 instance and pull the repo from my GitHub which contains my react app. Then I go into the folder in server and ran npm start trying to start deployment, but occurs these warnings, but when I run npm start locally, the web page shows correctly. (this is my first time doing the AWS deployment so I am not sure if this is ok even if with these warnings and if so what I should do next to make my web page appear?)
[image]

Comment: That has nothing to do with AWS... You had all of those warnings in the console while developing... The warnings are self-explanatory... Clean up your code and redeploy...

Comment: that code warnings dont affect your app running, just related to linting, but worth to fix

Comment: Yeah, most of your warnings are unused variables!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the warnings, it doesnt affect your app running but it's worth to fix because it improves your app quality and remove some bundles that are not used.

---

To deploy your website, you have to use `npm run build`.

`npm run build` creates a build directory with a production build of your app.

After you successfully built your app, use `nginx` to host your build directory.

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

If you are on ubuntu, that will install nginx.

And update `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` with the below content:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        root  ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Now restart the `nginx` and you will see your app running on your EC2 ip address.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: can you talk more specifically about how to update the default file? the port number for my local react project is set to 3001

Comment: Your app is hosted at 3001 when you run your app in development. The build folder is just static files and we are gonna serve this with nginx. You can just use the above configuration, just replace `ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY`. It will host your app on 80 port.

Comment: Just to make sure, is it /var/www/my_build_directory? because I saw the others do this

Comment: you can built and move it to their

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors, so you do not NEED to fix them. They are (I think) ESLint warnings. They are meant to make your code better, but it will not cause an error when you run it.